# Android module supporting different languages (without application context)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, multilingual, modular

I was trying to develop an android module with support for different languages.
I can create a strings .xml file but **without appropriate context** i cannot access it. For the sake of simplicity and to hold on to clean architectural concepts i don't want to receive any context parameters(*some parts are meant to live longer than usual*).
I have also tried using Kotlin data structures for the purpose, but they doesn't look like a good practice.

so, Is there any recommended way of doing this?
or Is there anything that con be done to have *asset or resource* files accessible from independent modules **without any application context**?

Comment: Context is how Android handles Locales and user settings that affect languages and resources. There's no way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access resource files, you have to use context. Or you can use static variables if you are determined not to use context, which is not a preferred way. You can pass *resources* as a param which can be provided by creating statically or by dependency injection.

Comment: Hi, actually what i am planning to build is an independent library module with support for different languages. which i cannot guarantee to have called from context based components. so extension got ruled out, and about static variables, they seemed difficult to maintain but still they are  there as a last resort.